# Node.js proxy HTTP,HTTPS requests for Google Analytics

Tags: node.js, proxy, google-api, google-analytics-api

I have a Node.js application which uses the [Google Analytics API](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) to read some parameters from my Google Analytics project. However I am using this application behind a corporate proxy. How do I proxy all my requests, http as well as https for google analytics.

When using npm I use this:

```
proxy=http://domain\User:password@host:port/
https-proxy=http://domain\User:password@host:port/
```

This works fine for npm, however it does not work for node.

Here is my code, which works on an open network, but fails

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var key = require('../keys/myKey.json');
const VIEW_ID = 'ga:123456789';

var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT( key.client_email, null, key.private_key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'], null);
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
if (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return;
}
var analytics = google.analytics('v3');
  queryData(analytics);
});

function queryData(analytics) {
  analytics.data.ga.get({
    'auth': jwtClient,
    'ids': VIEW_ID,
    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews,ga:sessions',
    'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath,ga:date',
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': '2017-03-13',
    'max-results': 10,
 }, function (err, response) {
 if (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return;
 }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
 });  
}
```

Error:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 216.58.199.173:443
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1087:14)
 code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
 errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
 syscall: 'connect',
 address: '216.58.199.173',
 port: 443 }
```

Comment: Found any solution ? I run a con job to get views of different pages of contents and I often get this error in the middle of cron job execution after a few calls.

Comment: I ended up doing something else. But it depends on the platform you are working on. On Unix the environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY might be useful....